# Filter dataframe with exact string match

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way that `str.contains` filter only the exact match of string rather than partial match

```
List = ['good', 'bad']
```

df

```
  col
1 good
2 this is good 
3 good boy
4 bad dream
5 goodman
6 badboy
7 bad 

df[(df['col'].str.contains('|'.join(List),na=False, ))]
```

**Desired output**

```
1 good
6 bad
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `isin` in this senario

**Ex:**

```
data = ['good', 'bad']
print(df[df['col'].isin(data)])
```

**Output:**

```
    col
0  good
6   bad
```